# How to automate PIM login in Azure?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azureportal

How to automate PIM login in Azure. Daily it takes 3-5 mins to activate the login and which is valid for 8 hours, so again whenever it is required I need to reactivate it. Please suggest any automation approach for PIM Login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To active the PIM automatically, you could follow the steps below.

1.Create [automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-account)(need to create Run As account) and [runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook)(powershell type).

2.Navigate to the automation account in the portal-> `Modules gallery` -> search for `AzureADPreview` module and import it.

3.Follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal) to assign the `Global Administrator` to the Run As account i.e. the service principal, just search for the name of your automation account, the name of the service principal has the format as `automationaccount_xxxxxxxx`.

4.In your runbook, use the script below to login with the service principal, use [`Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/powershell-for-azure-ad-roles#activate-a-role-assignment) to active an eligible assignment for a user you need.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzureAD `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 

    Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId 'aadRoles' -ResourceId '926d99e7-117c-4a6a-8031-0cc481e9da26' -RoleDefinitionId 'f55a9a68-f424-41b7-8bee-cee6a442d418' -SubjectId 'f7d1887c-7777-4ba3-ba3d-974488524a9d' -Type 'UserAdd' -AssignmentState 'Active' -schedule $schedule -reason "dsasdsas"

}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
```

5.Navigate to the runbook in the portal -> Schedules -> create and link a recurrence schedule to your runbook, e.g. every day, details depend on you.

Comment: Thanks Joy. I will check it and try it.